# How to get Firefox Web App in full screen mode now mozApps is desupported

Tags: android, firefox, web-applications, manifest

Now that we can no longer install FireFox Web Apps on Android: -
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Marketplace/API/DOMApplicationsRegistry/install

How can I achieve the full-screen Web App feel minus the browser chrome? "Pin to homescreen" still leaves the URL and tab-controls up there :-(

I understand that the Mozilla Marketplace is now dead but why can't we still load the manifest?

This was ALL useful stuff: -

```
{
  "name": "hypoCampus",
  "type": "web",
  "description": "hypoCampus Web App",
  "launch_path": "/civitas.html",
  "icons": {
    "128": "/icon1.png"
  },
  "permissions": {
    "geolocation": {
      "description": "Required to map your location"
      },
    "desktop-notification": {
      "description": "Required to receive hypoCampus notifications"
    }
  },
  "version": "1.0",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Richard Maher",
    "url": "http://a.b.c"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "fullscreen": "true"
}
```